# Como criar um método generico que recebe uma classe entidade qualquer, e inicia uma sessao no hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, genéricos

Boa noite,

Estou tentando criar um método que receba uma classe entidade qualquer e um ID para iniciar uma sessao no hibernate. A ideia é fazer um DAO generico pra pegar apenas o ID das entidades que eu desejar.

Segue o código que estou tentando fazer:

```
public class GenericDAO<T> {

public T getEntity(T entity, int id){
    Session session = null;
    Object result = null;
    try {
        session = PoliGenericDAO.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria("AQUI VEM A CLASSE GENERICA".class);
        result = crit.uniqueResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("getBasic.GenericClass.Error: " + e);
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Meu código para pegar um usuário com um ID *x* é o segunite:

```
teamModel.getUserList().add(userDao.getUserById(user.getId()));
```

E gostaria que ficasse dessa forma:

```
teamModel.getUserList().add(genericDao.getEntity(Entity, user.getId()));
```

*OBS: Onde neste caso, **'Entity'** seria a classe User*

A ideia aqui é fazer o minimo de consultas ao banco possível, já que usando o meu método atual, eu tenho como retorno do banco, a entidade completa, que neste caso eu n preciso.

Comment: Mas como você garante que todos os objetos passados vão ter o atributo Id se eles são genéricos? Acredito que o que você deveria fazer é declarar uma interface com os atributos/métodos necessários, implementar essa entidade nas suas entidades, e então receber objetos que implementam tal interface em `getEntity`

Comment: A maneira mais correta é você ter suas entidades padronizadas, criar uma classe abstrata `BaseEntity` por exemplo contendo o id, todas as entidades irão derivar dela. Em sua `GenericDAO` você pode então indicar que `T extends BaseEntity`, resolvendo o problema apontado pelo @user140828

Comment: Obrigado @ngueno, vou tentar dessa forma.